# Lightgbm early stopping not working properly

Tags: python, lightgbm

I'm using lightgbm for a machine learning task.

I want to use early stopping in order to find the optimal number of trees given a number of hyperparameters.
However, lgbm stops growing trees while still improving on my evaluation metric.

Below I've attached my specifications:

```
params = {
'max_bin' : [128],
'num_leaves': [8],
'reg_alpha' : [1.2],
'reg_lambda' : [1.2],
'min_data_in_leaf' : [50],
'bagging_fraction' : [0.5],
'learning_rate' : [0.001]
}

mdl = lgb.LGBMClassifier(n_jobs=-1, n_estimators=7000, 
                     **params)
mdl.fit(X_train, y_train, eval_metric='auc', 
          eval_set=[(X_test, y_test)], early_stopping_rounds=2000, 
        categorical_feature=categorical_features, verbose=5)
```

After some time lightgbm gives me the following result:
[image: example]

lgbm concludes that an auc of 0.7326 is not better than 0.70995 and stops.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: lowering learning_rate an order of magnitude lower than the default one and increasing the number of boosting rounds 70 times above default may easily lead to overfitting, so make sure you also get some metrics on an untouched dataset (e.g. out-of-time)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is working properly : as said in [doc for early stopping](https://lightgbm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Parameters.html#early_stopping_round) :

> will stop training if one metric of one validation data doesn’t
>   improve in last early_stopping_round rounds

and your logloss was better at round 1034.

Try to use [first_metric_only](https://lightgbm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Parameters.html#first_metric_only) = True or remove logloss from the list (using metric param)

Comment: Interestingly, when I try to do this in the context of a `cross_val_predict` I get errors with both 'first_metric_only' and 'metric'. I can still do early stopping, but I wonder if the sklearn API does not support keeping early stopping to a single metric.

The following runs with expected behavior:
`predictions = cross_val_predict(self.model, X=data, y=labels, cv=self.my_splitter, method='predict_proba',  fit_params={'eval_metric': my_custom_eval, 'eval_set': [(X_test, y_test)], 'early_stopping_rounds': 10 })`, but errors occur if I sneak a 'metric' or 'first_metric_only'param in.

Comment: Officially, of course, LightGBM sklearn API does not support any of this.. but I'm wondering if I'm doing something wrong.